# SiriKit Intent Handler not being called

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

I have an app that incorporated Siri Intents and they work well. You can have Siri launch the app and it will perform the action as expected. All of my intents need to happen in the app so I do not have an extension for them.

However using the Shortcuts app, when I use my shortcut the app will just stop in my app and not continue so Siri is not receiving the handler response.

Right now my delegate will open from an action inside of the NSUserActivity call and I will use a custom class to determine which Shortcut it is and perform said action.

I do have that custom class conforming to the IntentHandler Protocol for each action and I call a .success response in the completion handler.

Heres where I think I may be mistaken. I manually call the Handler protocol inside of my custom class.

```
func handleSiri(_ intent: INItent) {
 if intent is ActionIntent {
     func handle(intent: ActionIntent, completion: @escaping (ActionIntent Response) -> Void) {
       let response = DisconnectIntentResponse.init(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
       print("Intent was a success")
       completion(response)
    }
  }
}
```

However Siri never completes. Should I be calling this manually? Do I need to have an extension call these functions?

Comment: could you find a solution for this?

Comment: If your app isn't using the extension there is no callback. If you are asking about the Shortcuts app just set the action to not need screen

Answer (score -1):

The only reason why this is not called is because you have not added the Voice Intent extension into your `dependencies` list under `Build Phase` section for your App Target.